# How do I perform multiple keypresses with Python keyboard controller module

Tags: python, module, keyboard, repeat

I am trying to write better code so that I do not have to write these lines
multiple times.

How do I perform multiple keypresses using the Python keyboard controller module?

Can I do something like, keyboard.press(Key.down) * 4

```
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
```

Answer (score 0):

for loop would be better

```
[keyboard.press(key.down) for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: A for loop without the list comprehension would be even better. List comprehensions are for creating lists, which is not the goal here.

Comment: yes you are right